# Find this integral

Tags: calculus, integration, sequences-and-series, complex-analysis

If $\phi(x)$ is an arbitrary normalized function, $\mu \in \Re$,

Prove that
$$
\lambda \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} dx \, \left|\sqrt{|\mu|}\cdot \phi(\mu x) \right|^2 x^n= \frac B {|\mu|^n}
$$

and find $B$.

Comment: Your integral has an arbitrary function in it; obviously there can't be any general procedure that will always find the integral. Do you have some more context that might e.g. indicate restrictions on what $\phi$ might be, or kinds of partial answer that might be useful to you?

Comment: To make my point more explicit: pick almost any definite integral and it should be possible to find $\phi,\mu,\lambda$ for which your integral equals that integral. So asking for a general solution to evaluating your integral is kinda the same as asking for a general solution to evaluating *any* integral.

Comment: Yes. It's an exersice from quantum mechanics. $V(x)=\lambda x^{n}$. $\phi(x)$ is a physical state. And if $<\phi_{\mu}|=\sqrt{|\mu|}\cdot\phi(\mu x)$ I need to find $<\phi_{\mu}|V(x)|\phi_{\mu}>$

Comment: Maybe you just need to show that B does not depend on $\mu$ and is just equal to the expectation of the potential for the $\mu = 1$ state.

Comment: @user121049 yes. B does not depend on $\mu$ but i don't know how to prove this and find B.

Comment: @GarethMcCaughan Yes. It's an exersice from quantum mechanics. $V(x)=\lambda x^{n}$. $\phi(x)$ is a physical state. And if $<\phi_{\mu}|=\sqrt{|\mu|}\cdot\phi(\mu x)$ I need to find $<\phi_{\mu}|V(x)|\phi_{\mu}>$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $I(\lambda,\mu)$ be your integral. Then, if $\mu\neq0$,
\begin{eqnarray}
I(\lambda,\mu) & =\lambda |\mu|\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} dx \, |\phi(x\mu)|^2 x^n \\
& = \lambda |\mu|^{-n}\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}dt \, |\phi(t)|^2 t^n
\end{eqnarray}
The value depends on $\phi $, even if $ \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} dt \, |\phi(t)|^2=1$.

If $\mu=0$, $I(\lambda,\mu)=0$.